# Kyocera Mita 4030 problem printing envelopes

Tags: network-printer, envelope-printer

My Kyocera Mita 4030 network printer will not print envelopes.  My operating system is Windows XP.  I have tried to print envelopes from both Microsoft Word and WordPerfect 12, matching the printing preferences on the software to the printer settings for printing envelopes.  Each time the printer displays "error in print mode"  Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several type of drivers for Kyocera printing products. Try to use another type of driver, for example - KX, if you use PCL and vice versa.
Also maybe you need manually select paper type in panel on printer and/or put your envelopes into manual feed tray.